# How to hide horizontal scrollbar but still able to scroll

Tags: html, css

I have a div with 3 div where every div scroll independently.

```
<div class="divWrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

.item {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  overflow-scrolling: touch;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 16px;
  font-size: 0;
}
```

While scrolling i want to hide the scroll bar. on Windows all browser don't show scrollbar but on MAC scrollbar is visible.
Is there a way to get scrolling without having the scrollbar visible?

Comment: **CSS** ::-webkit-scrollbar: display: none

Comment: @ZeusZdravkov  thanks it works for me

Comment: Note that that will only work in Webkit browsers and those that recoginise the `-webkit-` prefix.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide scroll bar, but while still being able to scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-while-still-being-able-to-scroll)

Answer (score 7):

## Custom scrollbar in Webkit browsers

---

So the **CSS** is

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

More at this topic: https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/

Answer (score 1):

use CSS code below

```
.row-cards  {
    display: flex;   
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
    scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
    
   

  }
```

This div class name is `.row-cards` for this the horizontal scroll bar functions would be active but the scroll bar would be hidden allowing for a smooth look and feel

Answer (score -5):

It should be `oveyflow-x: hidden` not `overflow-x: auto`

Comment: That way you won't be able to scroll horizontally.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll?rq=1

Comment: @OkeTega that is for vertical scroll.